# Run the same function with the same arguments 10 times and get results

Tags: python, multithreading, concurrency, multiprocessing

I'm looking for the smartest way to run 10 times the same function with the same argument and store the results.

The straightforward solution is:

```
def f(a):
    // do stuff
    return a

results = []
same_argument = 10

for x in range(0,10):
    results.append(f(same_argument))
```

This works but I believe the process would take much less time if the 10 processes could be run concurrently.

[The multi-process `map` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool.map) seems like it would do the job but it only takes an iterable argument. I could just pass it a list of 10 times the same argument but it doesn't feel right.

Is there any other built-in way designed to deal with my issue?

Comment: You can use a generator expression `with Pool(10) as p:results = p.map(f, (same_argument for _ in range(10)))` for python3

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd just use a `pool` and pass the same argument a bunch of times...

```
n_times = 10
results = pool.map(f, [same_argument] * n_times)
```

It's quick, and it's easy to tell what is going on.  The only downside is that it takes a little intermediate storage -- This is likely negligible compared to the amount of storage you need to hold the actual results.

Of course, if you're really worried about the storage overhead, you should be able to use [`itertools.repeat(same_argument, n_times)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.repeat)...

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor -- `pool.map(f, (arg for _ in xrange(n))` would work (with modifications for py3k obviously).  I suggested a different alternative using `itertools.repeat`, but again, the intermediate storage is likely to be a non-issue for reasonable numbers of `n`.  You're not even creating new objects here -- Only more references which takes as much memory as a pointer (~8bytes each)...

Answer (score 0):

What about list comprehension?

```
results = [f(same_argument) for _ in xrange(10)]
```

Where the "_" is used to make syntax validation tools (like pylint) not complain about unused variables.